# adding user_id and name to a separate table whenever a user register based on role

Tags: database, hooks

```
add_action( 'register_new_user', newfun);
function newfun( $user_id ){
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) && in_array( 'latepoint_agent', $user->roles ) ) {
    global $wpdb;




    $status = $wpdb->query('INSERT INTO `wp_latepoint_agents` (`wp_user_id`) VALUES ('.$user_id.')');   
}

}
```

The Problem is this doesnot work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You are missing the quotes around your function newFun, it should be 'newFun', add_action('register_new_user', 'newFun');  within quotes.

Comment: I tested, Its not the Quotes For sure!